# Print statements not working in if/elif/else block

Tags: python

I have a project that I am trying to redo. It is for a coursera course on Interactive Python programming. The deadline for submission has already passed so I am not violating the honor code here, just wanting to understand why the code I am now working on for the same project is not working.

The game is Guess The Number. None of the print statements in the if block print out at all, and I of course think they should be, ergo I have made a mistake and I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is. I have gone over several other students projects during the evaluation phase and still cannot see why my code is incorrect.

The game executes in the browser here [Game In Browser here](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user3-3bIj15RoOx-3.py)

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
# Sanderson, Steven
# template for "Guess the number" mini-project
# input will come from buttons and an input field
# all output for the game will be printed in the console

import simplegui
import random
import math

# initialize global variables used in your code
secret = 0         # The secret number
guesses = 0        # The amount of guesses you will have left
guess_count = 0    # How many guesses you made
range_limit = 100  # The number range of the game


def init():
    # Here I reference the global variables because they
    # are now inside of a function being referenced locally
    global range_limit
    global secret

    # This following line limits the amount of guesses
    # the player can have based upon the given 
    # range_limit of the game
    guesses = int(math.ceil(math.log(range_limit,2)))

    # This following line of code generates a secret
    # number for the specified range of the game,
    # it has been initialized to a range of 100 to 
    # start the game
    secret = random.randrange(0, range_limit)

    # Converts range_limit to a string to print to console
    print "Play Guess The Number. The range is 0 to", + range_limit
    print "You have " +str(guesses) + " guesses for this game"
    print ""

# define event handlers for control panel

def range100():
    # button that changes range to range [0,100) and restarts
    global range_limit
    global secret
    global guesses
    range_limit = 100
    init()

def range1000():
    # button that changes range to range [0,1000) and restarts
    global range_limit, secret, guesses
    range_limit = 1000
    init()

def input_guess(guess):
    # main game logic goes here
    int_guess = int(guess)
    global guess_count
    global guesses
    global secret
    guesses += -1
    guess_count = guess_count + 1

    if int_guess == secret:
        print "You Win and did it in " +str(guess_count) + " guesses"
        print ""
        init()
    elif int_guess > secret:
        print "You guessed " +str(guess) + " guess lower"
        print "You have " +str(guesses) + " guesses left"
        print ""
    elif int_guess < secret:
        print "You guessed " +str(guess) + " guess higher"
        print "You have " +str(guesses) + " guesses left"
        print ""
    if guesses == 0:
        print "You ran out of guesses, the secret was " +str(secret)
        print ""
        init()


# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Guess The Number!", 200, 200)

# register event handlers for control elements
frame.add_button("Range [0, 100)", range100, 125)
frame.add_button("Range [0, 1000)", range1000, 125)
frame.add_input("Enter your guess here and press enter", input_guess, 125)

# start frame
frame.start()
init()

# I know my code is not the best, constructive criticisim in order to help me
# be a better coder is appreciated :)
```

Here is a sample output that I just ran. I printed out `secret`, `guess_count` and `guesses` and in that order.

```
71
0
0
You guessed 25 guess higher
You have -1 guesses left

71
1
-1
You guessed 25 guess higher
You have -2 guesses left

71
2
-2
You guessed 25 guess higher
You have -3 guesses left
```

It also looks like the init() is not working when the buttons are pressed as the count is not being reset, scratching head.[image: init() possibly not working right either]

Comment: If you're using globals, you're probably doing it wrong. Try using classes to contain both variables and methods.

Comment: May I suggest putting print statements throughout various points in your code to see how far it is actually executing? In `input_guess`, for example, place a `print "guess:", guess` and `print "secret", secret` right before the `if` statements.

Comment: I'm assuming that the print statements work everywhere else.

Comment: Thank you all so much. Under the def input_guess(guess) block I typed the following and it all kicked out right except for the amount of guesses I have left: int_guess = int(guess)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the lines

```
print repr(guess), type(guess), repr(secret), type(secret)
print guess == secret, guess > secret, guess < secret
```

right before the `if` branches, you see (something like):

```
'23' <class 'str'> 4 <class 'int'>
False False False
```

You're comparing a string to an integer, which in Python 3 gives `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()` but in Python 2 will silently return unexpected behaviour (based on the name of the class, if memory serves, but since we shouldn't be doing it anyway I never manage to remember the details.)  To be specific:

```
>>> "47" < 200
False
>>> "47" < 47
False
>>> "47" < 2
False
>>> 100 < "23"
True
>>> 100 < "1"
True
>>> 100 < "-23"
True
```

Convert the user input to an integer, and then you can start working through the next issue :^)

```
You guessed 5
5 <class 'int'> 35 <class 'int'>
False False True
You guessed 5 guess higher
You have -1 left
```

Comment: I was able to get things coming out, but now just like in your input I am getting

`You have -1 left`

It seems like to me that `guesses` is not being referenced from the `def init()` definitions and so now I am trying to figure out why that seems to be happening.